# Set different constraints for each orientation in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

The question sounds way harder than it is. Simply all I want to do is to be able to set a different layout for, I already added a landscape orientation, and recreated the whole design the way I desire in landscape. However, the app restarts each time I rotate the phone, if I add android:configChanges="orientation" in manifest, it does save the state but not the way I set in landscape. The app is 4 layouts in each orientation. So if I could just make different constraints for landscape the doesn't interrupt the original portrait it could solve my problem.
sorry for the poor explanation. It's my first week with Android.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in designing different layouts for different orientations.

For the state, you should override the onSaveInstanceState() method in Java.

Using that, you can save the state of the application and then inflate the layout the way you like in Java.